# Is there any side effect in the perl expression $a = $a++;

Tags: perl, auto-increment

Would be someone please to explain the next:

In the "Programming Perl" book postfix autoincrement operator is described, as

> when placed after, they (`$a--` , `$a++`) increment or decrement the variable after returning the value.

So, as I understood, `$a++` is never used in void context, cause there has been said that

> they increment or decrement the **variable**

But in the next example value of the variable never changes:

```
my $a = 3;
$a = $a++;
say $a; #always outputs 3
```

So my assumption is that there is no reason to use post-autoincrement when value is assigned to the same variable, but then the definition from the "Programming Perl" should be considered wrong, cause operator does not affect variable, but value in variable (at least in that example). Is that right?

Appreciation in advance.

Comment: You have the correct assumption that $a = $a++ is redundant because it will not increment the variable until it is accessed again.

Comment: I would imagine that the pseudocode for the postfix autoincrement operator would be something like save old value of variable, increment variable, return old value. When you think of it that way, it's easy to see why your code doesn't change what's in `a`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why, both postfix autoincrement and autodecrement operators are actually quite often used in void context exactly because they affect the *variable* - not the *value*.

Your example works the way it works because variable gets post-incremented *before* its old value gets assigned to it. In other words, the order of

```
my $a = 3; $a = $a++;
```

...is...

```
1) $old_value = $a;
2) $a = $a + 1;
3) $a = $old_value;
```

Should you replace `$a = $a++` with `$b = $a++` in your example, and print values of $b and $a afterwards, you'll clearly see the difference: while `$a` becomes incremented (thus, equal to 4), `$b` gets assigned the old value of `$a` (3).

Comment: Sorry for my English but what does it mean "nails"? For me it seems true, except name $old_value, which I personally would like to change to "stack". Also my thanks to @simbabque

Comment: @caligula: I meant to say that this is a very good explanation. [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com/#en|uk|This%20nails%20it!): Це припечатав!

Comment: @simbabque Too bad I've already upvoted your answer: this translation alone deserves it... )))

Comment: I have no idea what I have copy/pasted there from google. ;-)

Comment: @caligula, "nails it", from "to nail it on the head", referring to a good hit of a hammer. It means the answer is exactly what was desired. Other expressions meaning the same thing include "hits the mark", "bullseye!" and "bingo!".

Answer (score 10):

> So my assumption is that there is no reason to use post-autoincrement
>   when value is assigned to the same variable, but then the definition
>   from the "Programming Perl" should be considered wrong, cause operator
>   does not affect variable, but value in variable. Is that right?

I think this is really about terminology.

There's `$a++` and `++$a`. They both affect the variable `$a`.

```
my $a = 3;
$a++;
say $a;
```

gives you `4`, but so does

```
my $a = 3;
++$a;
say $a;
```

The difference is in what they return.

`$a++` first returns the **old** value and then increments it. `++$a` does the increment first and then returns the **new** value.

```
my $a = 3;
say $a++;
say $a;
```

Gives you:

```
3
4
```

While:

```
my $a = 3;
say ++$a;
say $a;
```

prints:

```
4
4
```

But then you would hardly assign the return value of `$a++` to a variable. It's a lot more likely that you use it in another operation, where you first want the old value to be used and then the variable to be incremented.

Here are some very lame examples:

```
my $a = 3;
say $a while $a--;
```

Prints:

```
2
1
0
```

And:

```
my $a = 3;
say $a while --$a;
```

Prints:

```
2
1
```

Sometimes there are cases where you want the 0 or the 0th index of something. And sometimes you don't want it. Both is useful imho.